# Como enviar resolução atual da tela para PHP (no primeiro carregamento)?

Tags: php, javascript, resolução-de-tela

Eu sei que há várias formas de obter o tamanho da tela por javascript, etc, mas eu não encontrei uma forma satisfatória de conseguir **comunicar este tamanho para o PHP ANTES da carga da tela**.

Por exemplo, eu gostaria que o arquivo HTML/PHP abaixo conseguisse pegar a largura da tela de alguma forma na variável PHP  `$largura_tela`:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php echo $largura_tela; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Você não tem como comunicar isso antes porque o PHP executa antes do JavaScript. Serão necessárias no mínimo 2 requisições para fazer essa informação chegar no servidor.

Comment: @bfavaretto Tem razão. Poderia postar seu comentário como resposta para eu dar como aceita?

Comment: @Leo Caracciolo, tanto jquery como javascript rodam no lado cliente, a pergunta é como fazer o PHP ter essa informação na primeira carga, o que é impossível, somente se fizer um redirecionamento, daí já é a segunda carga.

Comment: @Leo Caracciolo, acho que você não entendeu ainda, a questão é como o PHP pode ter estes dados na primeira carga, não o jquery....

Comment: Rapaz, em que tempo você vive? Isso não é possível com PHP e todo mundo tá careca de saber. Estava apenas te disponibilizando uma alternativa que não dá refresh na página. Boa sorte ai pra vc.

Comment: @Leo Caracciolo, desculpe, é que eu pensei que você não havia entendido, mas agradeço seu esforço e sua atenção. Obrigado.

Comment: Tranquilo!! Foi bom que desenvolvi mais um script!

Answer (score 1):

Olha não entendo o motivo de querer essa informação no PHP, mas segue um exemplo de como poderia ser feito...

> Crie um arquivo chamado detectScreen.php e inclua ele em sua página principal:

```
<?php

@session_start();

if(isset($_GET['heigthJanela'])) {
    $_SESSION['screenInfo'] = [
        'heigthJanela' => $_GET['heigthJanela'],
        'widthJanela' => $_GET['widthJanela'],
        'heightTela' => $_GET['heightTela'],
        'widthTela' => $_GET['widthTela']
    ];
    echo '<script>
                window.history.go(-1);
            </script>';
    die;
} else {
    if(!isset($_SESSION['screenInfo'])) {
        echo '<script>
                window.location.href = "detectScreen.php?heigthJanela="+window.innerHeight+"&widthJanela="+window.innerWidth+"&heightTela="+screen.height+"&widthTela="+screen.width;
            </script>';
        die;
    }   
}
```

> Após isso você pode recuperar em seus códigos usando o exemplo abaixo exemplor (teste.php):

```
<?php include __DIR__ . '/detectScreen.php'; ?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php echo $_SESSION['screenInfo']['heightTela']; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: De fato não funciona. O ideal para deixar uma resposta é que ela seja testada. E pelo que estou vendo, não há como enviar a resolução da tela para php na primeira carga...

Comment: Atualizei a resposta! Agora está testada, na primeira carga não tem como mesmo, mas tem a alternativa acima.

Answer (score -1):

```php
<?php
if(!isset($_GET['r']))
{
echo "<script language=\"JavaScript\">
<!--
document.location=\"$PHP_SELF?r=1&Largeur=\"+screen.width+\"&Hauteur=\"+screen.height;
//-->
</script>";
}
else {

// Código para exibir em caso de detecção da resolução de exibição
if(isset($_GET['Largeur']) && isset($_GET['Hauteur'])) {
  $largura = $_GET['Largeur'];
  $altura = $_GET['Hauteur'];
}
else {
// $largura = "nao encontrada";
}
}
?>
```